# Want to strip a particular Character

Tags: php

Guys,currently I'm using this:

```
$meta = htmlspecialchars($m);
```

This one is stripping all the HTML chars..But i want to just remove "<" and ">"

How do i do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to replace them with their HTML equivalents or simply remove them?

Answer (score 4):

To remove all `<` and `>` characters from a string, use

```
$meta = str_replace(array('<','>'), '', $m);
```

Comment: There's no need to supply a blank array as the second arg, simply '' would suffice.

Comment: Hah, I was in the middle of double-checking that when you commented

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/searchru/public_html/web-search.phtml on line 49

Answer (score 1):

This will replace the `<` and `>` characters with '' (nothing).

```
$cleantext = str_replace(array('<', '>'), '', $text);
```

Or replace them with encoded characters.

```
$cleantext = str_replace(array('<', '>'), array('&lt;', '&gt;'), $text);
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/searchru/public_html/web-search.phtml on line 49

Comment: Have you checked your code on the preceeding lines?  You may have an unclosed `'`.

Comment: Yes,I did..But nothing found !!

Comment: It works in my test environment verbatim.  @Gareth's code does as well.

Comment: <?php $p = str_replace(' ', '+', $_GET['search']) ?>
<?php $plus = str_replace(array('<', '>'), '', $p);

Answer (score 0):

Use [str_replace()](http://php.net/str-replace)